# how to get the image using Jasny image upload and post in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, image-uploading

there's a similar question about this but honestly i still don't understand how it works.

here is the code:

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="myimage" accept="image/*"></span>
       <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my questions is:  1.) how will i pass the image using $_POST[] or $_FILES[] ?

2.) does the  `<input type="file" name="myimage" accept="image/*">` handles both when the user clicks the "Select Image" and "Change"?

3.) or what way can i pass the image and upload it on the server using PHP?

Comment: @Jasny - Arnold Daniels Sir can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

use  tag with enctype as multipart/form-data around this code to post your files.

Comment: A short example will be useful to illustrate your answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change version of the code above to latest one by changing: fileupload to fileinput. Else you will have trouble with displaying.

Here is simple example for you:

```
<form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
<div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 277px; height: 220px;">
<img src="../images/default_image.png" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 277px; max-height: 220px;"></div>
<div>
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file[]"></span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='SUBMIT' />
</form>
```

So when you submit the form, this will process upload.php. So to upload an image to server, you need to write code in this file to handle that. A simple code could be:

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // When you click submit the form
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ //check if there is a file has been submitted.
        // count and loop through array of files(if multiple images are uploaded)
        for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$i++)
        {
        // check if there is a file in the array
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
        {
              echo 'No file is uploaded'; 
        }
        else{
              Code to handle image upload and store image path to array 
        }
        All images path are in array, you need to serialize() it and save to database as normal
}
?>
```

Hope you might get the idea of how to use Jasny Fileinput to handle image upload.